# edit json file using script

Tags: scripts, text-editor, json

I have a json file that it has more than 30k lines, and I need to replace all instances of `}{` in the file with `},{` by using script shell or just a text editor like less or vim.

Comment: Irrelevant nitpick: less isn't an editor, it's just a pager (a text viewer, if you like).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `sed`:

```bsh
sed 's/}{/},{/g' orig.json > new.json
```

Or, to edit the file in place (this will copy the original to `orig.json.bak`):

```bsh
sed -i.bak 's/}{/},{/g' orig.json
```

Comment: If there is a return line between `}` and `{`,  `should I put sed 's/}/n{/},{/g' orig.json > new.json` ??

Comment: `\n` instead of `/n`. But that won't work.  See here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string

Comment: @YassineSihi no, if there's a return line then you are asking for something completely different and that won't work. That's why you shjould always include examples when asking this sort of question. `}{` is *not* the same as `} {` and not the same as `}\n{` or `}\t{`.